# How to remove accents / diacritic marks from a string in Qt?

Tags: string, qt, diacritics, qstring

How to remove diacritic marks from a string in Qt. For example, this:

```
QString test = QString::fromUtf8("éçàÖœ");
qDebug() << StringUtil::removeAccents(test);
```

should output:

```
ecaOoe
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278448/removing-accents-from-a-qstring

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is not straighforward, built-in solution in Qt. A simple solution, which should work in most cases, is to loop through the string and replace each character by their equivalent:

```
QString StringUtil::diacriticLetters_;
QStringList StringUtil::noDiacriticLetters_;

QString StringUtil::removeAccents(QString s) {
    if (diacriticLetters_.isEmpty()) {
        diacriticLetters_ = QString::fromUtf8("ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ");
        noDiacriticLetters_ << "S"<<"OE"<<"Z"<<"s"<<"oe"<<"z"<<"Y"<<"Y"<<"u"<<"A"<<"A"<<"A"<<"A"<<"A"<<"A"<<"AE"<<"C"<<"E"<<"E"<<"E"<<"E"<<"I"<<"I"<<"I"<<"I"<<"D"<<"N"<<"O"<<"O"<<"O"<<"O"<<"O"<<"O"<<"U"<<"U"<<"U"<<"U"<<"Y"<<"s"<<"a"<<"a"<<"a"<<"a"<<"a"<<"a"<<"ae"<<"c"<<"e"<<"e"<<"e"<<"e"<<"i"<<"i"<<"i"<<"i"<<"o"<<"n"<<"o"<<"o"<<"o"<<"o"<<"o"<<"o"<<"u"<<"u"<<"u"<<"u"<<"y"<<"y";
    }

    QString output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        QChar c = s[i];
        int dIndex = diacriticLetters_.indexOf(c);
        if (dIndex < 0) {
            output.append(c);
        } else {
            QString replacement = noDiacriticLetters_[dIndex];
            output.append(replacement);
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Note that `noDiacriticLetters_` needs to be a `QStringList` since some characters with diacritic marks can match to two single characters. For example `œ` => `oe`

Comment: Unless you do a composing Unicode normalization before and only want to replace graphemes that can be normalized to a single composite character, `diacriticLetters_` needs to be a QStringList, too.

Comment: I had to replace the 6th line with diacriticLetters_ = QString("ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ");

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a bit misleading. You seem to want to do more than merely remove diacritical marks (œ is a ligature letter without diacritics). I guess you want to turn any Unicode string into a roughly corresponding ASCII string?

For diacritics, you could perform a decomposing Unicode normalization (NFD or NFKD, depending on your specific needs) and then remove all characters of the "Mark" categories (`QChar::Mark_NonSpacing`, `QChar::Mark_SpacingCombining` and `QChar::Mark_Enclosing`).

For everything else (e.g. œ), I don't know of a generic solution. Create a look-up table with all your desired replacements and then search and replace (see Laurent's answer).

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution is to use QString::normalized, than remove the special characters.

```
QString test = QString::fromUtf8("éçàÖœ");
QString stringNormalized = test.normalized (QString::NormalizationForm_KD);
stringNormalized.remove(QRegExp("[^a-zA-Z\\s]"));
```

This is however a partial solution because it will not convert "œ" into "oe".

Answer (score 0):

There is crude way to partial solve your problem (just accents, but not ligatures such as "oe").

```
QString title=QString::fromUtf8("éçàÖ");
qDebug("%s\n", title.toLocal8Bit().data());
```

Comment: According to the Qt Assistant, this relies on undefined behavior!