# How to detect and replace non-ascii characters in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, replace, character

The problem is that I can't find an easy way how to detect and replace non-ascii characters such as `ąčęęėįšž` in Qt. I read a line from the file like `kažkodėl` and want to replace characters `ž`, `ė` to `z` and `e`. I will grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's not really an across-the-board solution and you want to replace certain characters with other certain characters, sounds to me like you want to set a QRegExp hunting for certain character sets that get [replaced](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qstring.html#replace-16) with a single character.

Also, see this link: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/38898-Accented-Character

---

**Edit:**
Does QString::normalize() do what you're looking for?
See this link: [Removing accents from a QString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278448/removing-accents-from-a-qstring)

Answer (score 2):

For detection, you can probably use [`QChar::toAscii()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qchar.html#toAscii) and check if the result is 0.

Looking at the details of [`QString::toAscii()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toAscii), you may actually be looking for toLatin1() . Note that toLatin1() for QString seems to use a '?' for the replacement character, not the '0' of QChar's toAscii(). (I'm not sure if Qt is erroneously equating latin1 and ascii here... but it seems to be claiming it is in the docs)

Comment: In Qt5 QString::toAscii() is deprecated and the docs tell you to use QString::toLatin1() instead.